# Python list write to CSV without the square brackets

Tags: python, csv

I have this main function:

```
def main():
    subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
    ipList,hostList,manfList,masterList,temp = [],[],[],[],[]
    ipList,hostList,manfList, = getIPs(),getHosts(),getManfs()
    entries = len(hostList)
    i = 0
    for i in xrange(i, entries):
        temp = [[hostList[i]],[manfList[i]],[ipList[i]]]
        masterList.append(temp) 
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(masterList)
```

My current output is that it successfully writes to CSV but my objective is to remove the square brackets.

I tried using `.join()` method however I understand that it only takes single lists and not nested lists.

How can I achieve this given that I'm using a 3 dimensional list? Note, I intend to add more columns of data in the future.

---

Edit:

My current output for 1 row is similar to:

> ['Name1,']    ['Brand,']  ['1.1.1.1,']

I would like it to be:

> Name1, Brand, 1.1.1.1,

Comment: how do you want the tree lists separated then?

Comment: Give an example output you'd like to see

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what your inputs look like and what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove bracket for values in `temp` while creating `masterList`, because it will be nested list. So, the code should be:

```
def main():
    subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
    ipList,hostList,manfList,masterList,temp = [],[],[],[],[]
    ipList,hostList,manfList, = getIPs(),getHosts(),getManfs()
    entries = len(hostList)
    i = 0
    for i in xrange(i, entries):
        temp = [hostList[i], manfList[i], ipList[i]]
        masterList.append(temp) 
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(masterList)
```

Comment: Excellent. You tied with King of Fools. Can you explain why this worked in your answer? I don't understand your first sentence.

Comment: `temp = [[hostList[i]], [manfList[i]], [ipList[i]]]` will create a **list of list**, e.g: `[['Name1'], ['Brand'],  ['1.1.1.1,']]`. When it append into `masterList`, `masterList` will be **list of list of list**.

Comment: `temp = [hostList[i], manfList[i], ipList[i]]` will create a **list**, e.g: `['Name1', 'Brand', '1.1.1.1,']`. When it append into `masterList`, `masterList` will be **list of list**.

Comment: The `writer.writerows` accept **list of list** (2-dim array) which is `masterList` as in my solution.

Comment: So, when you give **list of list of list** (which is *list of list* with *list of list* as the value) to `writer.writerows`, it will write the value (*list of list*) as string.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is strip a string of the data maybe?

```
import string
writer.writerows(str(masterList).translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '[]\'')
```

E.g.

```
>>> import string
>>> temp = [['1.1.1'], ['Name1'], ['123']]
>>> str(temp).translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '[]\'')
'1.1.1, Name1, 123'
```

In Python 3.6:

```
>>> temp = [['1.1.1'], ['Name1'], ['123']]
>>> str(temp).translate({ord('['): '', ord(']'): '', ord('\''): ''})
'1.1.1, Name1, 123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
temp = [[hostList[i]],[manfList[i]],[ipList[i]]]
```

to this:

```
temp = [hostList[i],manfList[i],ipList[i]]
```

Comment: Excellent. You tied with Edward Samuel. Can you explain why this worked in your answer?

Comment: @adampski Do you mean to explain why you should change it like i wrote? First variant does list of lists with one element in each. Second variant does list of elements, just what you need I think.

Comment: So when you write to file, you need to have list of lists with elements in each. But you have list of lists of lists, if you can call it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above, about the brackets removal, however if this is crucial to you for some reason, here is a function that takes a list as an input and returns you a csv row acceptable list.

```
def output_list(masterList):
    output = []
    for item in masterList:
        if isinstance(item,list): #if item is a list
            for i in output_list(item): #call this function on it and append its each value separately. If it has more lists in it this function will call itself again
                output.append(i)
        else:
            output.append(item)
    return output
```

You can use it in the line `masterList.append(temp)` as `masterList.append(output_list(temp))`, or even like this:

```
#in the end
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for i in masterList:
        writer.writerow(output_list(i))
```